# Transfer a row to another sheet then clear the original row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I saw this problem and the answer was perfect except that I do not want to delete the row. I only need the cells cleared of existing values.

[How to move a row into another sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/how-to-move-a-row-into-another-sheet)

Comment: Welcome. While it's very good that you included links to other questions on this site, questions should be self contained meaning it should include all the relevante details as the other question could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use something simple like this to "clear" the row either via the button or by including it in the previous script to be auto-executed

  ```
  function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                              var source = ss.getRange("Sheet1!X1");
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!A2"), {contentsOnly: true}); 
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!B2"), {contentsOnly: true});
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!C2"), {contentsOnly: true});
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!D2"), {contentsOnly: true});
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!E2"), {contentsOnly: true});
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!F2"), {contentsOnly: true});
                          source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!G2"), {contentsOnly: true}); }
  ```
- where **Sheet1!X1** is the empty cell that gets copied over the mentioned cells